# Class is returning None after the result

Tags: python, class, subclass

I have a class `User` and a subclass `Admin` that I am trying to work on, but when I try to call an instance of them I keep getting None returned after the result

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, height):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height

    def describe_user(self):
        print(f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}\n{self.age} " \
            f"years old\n{self.height} cm tall")

    def greet_user(self):
        print(f"Hi, {self.first_name} {self.last_name}! ")


class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, height):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, age, height)
        self.privileges = ['post', 'delete post', 'ban user']
        
    def show_privileges(self):
        print(f"{self.first_name} can:")
        for item in self.privileges:
            print(item)
    
person = Admin('John', 'Doe', 20, 180)
print(person.describe_user())
print(person.show_privileges())


John Doe
20 years old
180 cm tall
None
John can:
post
delete post
ban user
None
```

I am trying to find out why this happens and how to fix it

Comment: `describe_user()` is a print statement.  It doesn't return a value.  Likewise for `show_privileges()`.  If you want a function to return a value, it needs to have a `return` statement.

Answer (score 2):

`person.describe_user()` returns `None` implicitly since it doesn't have a `return` statement within the function body(it only prints a value). This causes `print(person.describe_user())` to print `None`.

The solution is to just write `person.describe_user()` without the extra `print()`, and similarly for the following line.

Answer (score 0):

`describe_user` and `show_privileges` do their own `print`ing; they don't have a return value, so they implicitly return `None`. Get rid of the `print` around the call to each of them, making the end of your code just:

```
person = Admin('John', 'Doe', 20, 180)
person.describe_user()
person.show_privileges()
```

and you won't print their useless return values (`None`).